# Как отследить результат нажатия на кнопку «Поделиться» VK / Facebook / Twitter?

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, facebook-api, twitter-api

Есть кнопки «Поделиться» ВКонтакте, Twitter и Facebook.

Когда пользователь нажимает — открывается диалоговое окно и нажимает «Поделиться». Мне нужно узнать ответ — поделился ли пользователь или нет? В API ничего подобного не нашёл.

Кто что может предложить? Как можно получить ответ? Если можно было бы ифреймить диалоговое окно, то можно было обработать событие клика на кнопку «Поделиться», но увы.

Можно ещё без диалоговых окон, но не знаю как это сделать.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В ХэшКоде с API похоже - не очень, нашел решение. Чтоб узнать ответ, нужно подключить

VK

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://userapi.com/js/api/openapi.js?49"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
VK.init({ apiId: идентификатор_приложения, onlyWidgets: true });
</script>
```

FB

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Twitter

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

Далее для ВК

```
VK.Observer.subscribe(‘widgets.like.shared’, function(likeCount)
{
    //если пользователь опубликовал ваш пост
});
```

Для ФБ

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(opt_target) {
    //если нажали на кнопку  "рекомендовать"
});
```

Для Tw

```
trackTwitterHandler_ = function (intent_event) {
    var opt_target;
    if (intent_event && intent_event.type == 'tweet' || intent_event.type == 'click') {
        var socialAction = intent_event.type + ((intent_event.type == 'click') ? '-' + intent_event.region : ''); //тип нажатия
        //ну, как пример, проверка на то, твиттнули ли
        if (socialAction == 'tweet') {
            //если титнули 
        }
        //еще можно обрабатывать нажатие по числу твиттов и тд}}; 
        intent_handler = function (intent_event) {
            trackTwitterHandler_(intent_event);
        };
        twttr.events.bind('click', intent_handler);
        twttr.events.bind('tweet', intent_handler);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Лично у меня этот код не сработал:

```
VK.Observer.subscribe(‘widgets.like.shared’, function(likeCount)
{
    //если пользователь опубликовал ваш пост
     somefunction()
});
```

Я сделал так:

```
var somefunction() {};
$('#vkshare0 a').click(function(){
VK.Observer.publish("widgets.like.shared",8);
})
```