# Проверка шаринга в соц сетях

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, facebook, odnoklassniki-api

Столкнулся с проблемой проверки, поделился ли пользователь записью или нет.

Есть ссылки с помощью которых делимся записью:

```
ВК - http://vk.com/share.php?url=сайт
ФБ - https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u= сайт
ОД - http://www.odnoklassniki.ru/dk?st.cmd=addShare&st._surl= сайт
```

Что уже толлько не делал, но ничего не работает.
Делал как в этом посте [Как отследить результат нажатия на кнопку «Поделиться» VK / Facebook / Twitter?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/164398/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%92%D0%9A-%D0%A4%D0%91-%D0%A2%D0%92) но результатом не дало.
ПО ФБ на кликл вешал функцию:

```
    $('#fblink').on('click',function(){
            FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        link: 'сайт',

    }, function(response){alert(response)});
    });
```

Но говорит что app_Id обезательно нужно указать хотя я его указываю как показано в офф документации:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'code',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.5'
    });
};

(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам для начала надо зарегистрировать Ваше приложение, а оттуда уже взять Ид приложения.
Не забывайте о том что документация это всё таки пример.

Comment: Да я как бы указал  что ключ у меня есть. Но за совет всеравно спасибо)

Comment: тогда второй вопрос, что происходит у Вас в консоле?

Comment: В консоли чисто за исключением "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token F"  назойливая ошибка, правда я сомниваюсь что проблема в ней.

Comment: для Вк есть интересный метод http://vk.com/dev/wall.get - он получает все записи пользователя, по ответу можно найти какая запись Вам нужна, но есть более компактный. http://vk.com/dev/wall.get - данный метод произведёт поиск определённой записи. Для Facebook'a я думаю не составит труда разобраться

Comment: Посмотрим, спасибо

Comment: @YuriyChmil удачи