# Своя кнопка поделиться

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Для сайта нужно сделать свою кнопку "Поделиться" в различных социальных сетях. Как отследить, пользователь действительно поделился записью или только нажал на кнопку на сайте и передумал длиться страницей? По возможности желательно отследить конкретную страницу с поделившейся записью, что бы потом лично проверить - поделился пользователь или нет.
Можно ли это сделать и каким образом?

Comment: Возможно дубликат - [Как отследить результат нажатия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/164398/Как-отследить-результат-нажатия-на-кнопку-Поделиться-vk-facebook-twitter)

Comment: То, что нужно. Только для всех социальных сетей если делать, то как?

Comment: Для всех и сразу - никак. У всех разные API.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь вы можете отметить любую сеть. И ставьте код . Когда кто то поделился то возле значка пишет число.
https://tech.yandex.ru/share/